# Flex 3 equivalent of '<fx:Declarations>'?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4

I'm trying to migrate a Flex 4 project backwards to Flex 3, and I need to move stuff mapped in a `<fx:Declarations>` block in MXML. Does Flex 3 have something similar to this? It's been a while since I've done Flex 3.

Comment: out of curiosity, why migrating down?

Comment: Flex 4 is backwards-compatible with Flex 3. Why the need to switch the SDK or rewrite your whole application, i.e. what exactly is your goal?

Comment: Application is written in Flex 3, I'm writing essentially a module for it, and believe me, I have recommended Flex 4 from the start. It's one of those things you hate to do, but just have to do it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no equivalent in Flex 3. You can declare things alongside your other components. The [difference in Flex 4](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex3and4_differences.html) makes the separation between visual and non-visual items (including things like effects, validators, formatters, data declarations, and RPC classes) clearer.

For example, in Flex 4 you would do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:String>Hello, world!</fx:String>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <!-- Component defintions -->

</s:Application>
```

but in Flex 3, you would do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">

    <mx:String>blah</mx:String>

    <!-- Component defintions -->

</mx:Application>
```

You can, however, define your variables and whatever other declarations (visual or not) within the `<mx:Script>` or `<fx:Script>` tag in Flex 3 and 4 respectively.

If you're stuck on other changes, search Adobe's website about [migrating from flex 3 to flex 4](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/search/index.cfm?term=migrating+from+flex+3+to+flex+4&siteSection=devnet%3Aflex.html) to see what other changes you may have to make.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to define separately and off course not supported

```
 <fx:Declarations>

 </fx:Declarations>
```

in the Flex 3.

In the declaration tag you define non visual tags like Effects, services tags etc.But there is no exact tag in Flex 3 SDK for non visual tags.

Answer (score 1):

Start with root application tag.There is no need for `<fx:declaration>` in flex3 just assign components inside the root tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    layout="vertical"
    backgroundColor="#000000"
    backgroundGradientAlphas="[0.0,0.0]"
    paddingTop="30"
    applicationComplete="init()"
    preloader="com.nickkuh.preload.Preloader"
    viewSourceURL="srcview/index.html">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            /*script area*/
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <!-- your controls can define here -->

    <mx:Panel id="appPanel" visible="false" width="600" height="500" showEffect="{fadeIn}" />

</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is none. The older version of the framework will assume any non-visual element is a "deceleration". The decelerations tag was added so that component factories could be defined using MXML in a spark skin.

*edit*

But if I remember correctly, they do need to go in the top level MXML tag. I could be wrong though...