# could not resolve <mx:String>

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm very new to the Flex Programming.
I was writing a sample program.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <mx:String id="message">Hello, World</mx:String>
    <mx:Label text="{message}"/>
</s:Application>
```

But getting an error "could not resolve  to a component implementation"

I have the following queries.
What does  , tags refers to.
why i'm getting the above error.Please help

Answer (score 2):

This code should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <fx:String id="message">Hello, World</fx:String>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <mx:Label text="{message}"/>
</s:Application>
```

**What I did was:**

1. Changed your string to `<fx:String>`
2. Moved it into the `<fx:Declarations>` tag.

**Reason:**

It looks a little like you trying to compile with the Flex 4 SDK and are mixing a little of Flex 3 and Flex 4. Anything starting with the namespace *"s"* is a Flex 4 Spark components. Anything with the namespace *"mx"* is from Flex 3.

In Flex 3 you could declare variables in the code, right next to any visual component and they were all declared with the *"mx"* namespace. With Flex 4, they changed it so that declaring things that are not visual components (like variables) need to be placed in the `<fx:Declarations>` tag, which is why there is the comment *"Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here"*. They also changed the namespace of those non-visual elements to *"fx"*.

There is some explaination in [Flex 3 equivalent of ''?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132994/flex-3-equivalent-of-fxdeclarations)